# Question about congruence classes and reduced residue systems

Tags: elementary-number-theory, congruences, reduced-residue-system

Let $x$,$y$ be integers such that the reduced residue system modulo $y$ divides equally into congruence classes modulo $x$.

An example of this is $x=4$, $y=5$.

- The reduced residue system modulo $5$ is $\{1,2,3,4\}$
- These divide evenly into congruence classes of $4$ (one element to a congruence class).

Another example of this is $x=4$, $y=13$

- The reduced residue system modulo $13$ is $\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12\}$
- These equally divide into the congruence classes of $4$ since each class consist of the same number of elements (3 elements to a class each):
- $\{1,5,9\}$ congruent to $1 \pmod 4$
- $\{2,6,10\}$ congruent to $2 \pmod 4$
- $\{3,7,11\}$ congruent to $3 \pmod 4$
- $\{4,8,12\}$ congruent to $0 \pmod 4$

Is it always true that for any integer $z$ that is relatively prime to $x$, the reduced residue system modulo $y*z$ will also equally divide into congruence classes modulo $x$?

Here's an example of what I am talking about.

Let $z$ be $3$ which is relatively prime to $4$ with $x=4, y=5$

- The reduced residue system modulo $15$ is $\{1,2,4,7,8,11,13,14\}$
- These divide evenly into congruence classes of $4$ (two elements to a congruence class)
- $\{1,13\}$ congruent to $1\pmod 4$
- $\{2,14\}$ congruent to $2\pmod 4$
- $\{4,8\}$ congruent to $0\pmod 4$
- $\{7,11\}$ congruent to $3\pmod 4$

In this case, there $8$ elements in the reduced residue class and all congruence classes of $4$ are included an equal number of times.

Does it always follow that if $x,y$ have the relationship described, that for any integer $z$ that is relatively prime to $x$, that $y*z$ will also have this relationship?  I believe that the answer is yes.  I am trying to work on the argument that establishes this.

Here's the approach that I came up with:

(1)  $y*z$ consists of $z$ complete residue systems modulo $y$:

- $C_{y,1}: 1 \cdots y$
- $C_{y,2}: y+1 \cdots 2y$
- $\cdots$
- $C_{y,z}: (z-1)*y+1 \cdots yz$

(2) For each complete residue system, $R_{y,i}$, the elements will equally divide into the congruence classes modulo $x$.

Argument:  If $r \in R_{y,1}$, then $r+y \in R_{y,2}$.  So, it follows if $x \mid y$, then $r + y \equiv r \pmod x$.  If $x \nmid y$, then each element has a one-to-one mapping with a different congruence class.  Since each class of element maps to the same distinct class in $R_{y,2}$, the result follows.

(3)  To complete the argument, I want to show that I can take $z$ elements from $R_{y,1}, R_{y,2}, \cdots, R_{y,z}$ such that:

- For each $r_{y,1}$ I take, I can find an $r_{y,2}$ with the same congruence class modulo $x$ but a difference congruence class modulo $z$.
- I can repeat this process for $r_{y,3}$ and so on up until $r_{y,z}$.
- I can do this to the point that I have $\varphi(y)$ distinct pairings of $z$ elements each.
- This would then show that each pairing of $z$ elements forms a complete residue system modulo $z$.

Is there an easier way to prove this?  Is my reasoning sound?  Is there a more elegant way to complete the argument than my proposed step #3?  How would you state the argument for step #3?

Thanks very much!

Comment: Please give a precise definition and/or an example of what you mean by "reduced residue system modulo y divides equally into congruence classes modulo x." $\ \ $

Comment: Thanks for comment!  I've updated the question to add more examples.  I mean that if you divide up the reduced residue system modulo y into congruence classes modulo x, you will get the same number of elements in each congruence class.

Comment: Both examples are lacking the $\;0\;$ (zero) residue...

Comment: @Don, I am not clear on your point.  Isn't $4 \equiv 0 \pmod 4$?

Comment: @LarryFreeman, neither example is modulo $\;4\;$ ! The first one is modulo $\;5\;$ and the other one is modulo $\;13\;$ ...

Comment: @DonAntonio, apologies.  I am still not clear on your point.  My question is that if we take the list of the reduced residue system modulo 13 and view them as numbers so that we have: 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12 that 3 of them are congruent to 0 modulo 4, 3 of them are congruent 1 modulo 4, 3 of them are congruent to 2 modulo 4, and 3 of them are congruent to 3 modulo 4.  Will this also be the case if we look at the numbers that make up the reduced residue system modulo y*z?  Will they also divide up equally into congruence classes modulo 4?

Comment: Once again, @LarryFreeman: the list you gave of the residues modulo $\;13\;$ is **not** complete: there's lacking the residue $\;0=-13=13=26=-39\;$ , etc. Of course, it may be that you're interested in the *non-zero* residues modulo a prime...? About your question: your two examples $\;(5,13)\;$ are primes equal to $\;1\pmod 4\;$ so what you want will always work. But now try a prime $\;=3\pmod 4\;$ , say $\;7\;$ : the non-zero residues are $\;\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}\;$ and there's only one thate equals zero or three modulo $\;4\;$ , but two that equal $\;1\;or\;2\pmod 4\;$ ...

Comment: @DonAntonio, thanks!  I understand now.  To be clear, I am only interested in the reduced residue system, that is, the non-zero residues modulo $y$.  I agree that the reduced residue systems modulo a prime will not always divide equally.  My question is about when they do.  If they equally divide for the nonzero residues modulo $y$, will they also divide for the nonzero residues modulo $xy$?  I am trying to prove that the answer is yes.

Comment: "reduced residue system" is a system of representatives of **all** the residue classes, @LarryFreeman, including the zero one.

Comment: @DonAntonio, I understood that a "complete residue system" is the system of all residue classes.  Here's the wikipedia article: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reduced_residue_system

Comment: Exactly, @LarryFreeman: of **all** the residue classes, including the zero one.

Comment: @DonAntonio, I just realized that I never responded.  I am reasoning about the *reduced residue system* not the *complete residue system*.  I hope that clarifies my point.  Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a rather interesting question, which I found quite challenging to properly solve and then write this answer. Your conjecture is correct, but I have a few suggestions and there are several issues with your proof.

In your argument $(2)$, although it's supposed to be about $R_{y,i}$ for all $i$, it only discusses going from $R_{y,1}$ to $R_{y,2}$, with it implicitly assuming this is to be extended appropriately for all $i$. Also, it's not necessary to consider if $x \mid y$ because $x$ and $y$ must be relatively prime. Otherwise, if $\gcd(x, y) = d \gt 1$, then no element of the [reduced residue system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reduced_residue_system) modulo $y$ has a factor of $d$. Thus, it wouldn't include any of the congruence classes $md \; \forall \; 0 \lt m \le \frac{x}{d}$ modulo $x$, contradicting that each of these classes are equally represented.

Your $(3)$ states you "... can find an $r_{y,2}$ with the same congruence class modulo $x$ but a difference congruence class modulo $z$". The lower-case $r$ values are apparently meant to represent elements from the corresponding $R$ sets, but you should make this explicit. Also, I assume "difference" is meant to be "different", but you don't explain how & what it's different from. Nonetheless, since your third bullet point states "... distinct pairings of $z$ elements each", it seems the term different means distinct. However, a more significant issue is your fourth bullet point which states

> - This would then show that each pairing of $z$ elements forms a complete residue system modulo $z$.

You're trying to prove the congruence classes modulo $x$ are all equally represented, so it's not clear, at least to me, how having a complete residue system modulo $z$, which is relatively prime to $x$, would show the conjecture is true.

Here's how I would prove your conjecture instead. First, it's easier to deal with multiplying the value of $y$ by one prime at a time, since if the conjecture is proven true for any given prime, the steps can be repeated for each prime in turn to end up with the result for $z$. Note if $z = 1$, then there's nothing more to do. Otherwise, with $z \gt 1$, let

$$z = \prod_{i=1}^{n}p_i \tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$

where the $p_i$ are all of the $n \ge 1$ (not necessarily distinct) prime factors of $z$. Next, follow the procedure below to handle each of these primes in turn.

1. Let $C_{x}$ be the [complete residue system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covering_system) of integers modulo $x$ in $[1, x]$. Set $y_1 = y$ and $i = 1$.
2. Set $w_i = y_i \times p_i$ and let $R_{t}$ be the set of elements in $[1, w_i]$ which are coprime to $y_{i}$. As you basically did, let $R_{y_i}$ be the reduced residue system modulo $y_i$ of the integers in $[1, y_i]$. For each $e \in R_{y_i}$, since $\gcd(e, y_i) = 1$, then $\gcd(jy_i + e, y_i) = 1$ for each $1 \le j \lt p_i$. As well, for any $1 \le f \le y_i$ where $\gcd(jy_i + f, y_i) = 1$, then $\gcd(f, y_i) = 1$ meaning $f \in R_{y_i}$. Thus, there's a one-to-one mapping between the elements of $R_{y_i}$ and the integers coprime to $y_i$ in each $[jy_i + 1, (j + 1)y_i]$ region, so each of these regions has $|R_{y_i}|$ elements. Also, each congruence class $g \in C_{x}$ is shifted by $jy_i$ in $[jy_i + 1, (j+1)y_i]$ compared to $[1, y_i]$, so since each shift is to a unique congruence class, there's no change in how many there are of each congruence class. Thus, adding all of these same number of elements together for each $j$ means the number of elements of each congruence class in $C_{x}$ in $R_{t}$ is $p_i$ times the number in $R_{y_i}$. This is basically the argument you used in your $(2)$.
3. Have $R_{w_i}$ be the reduced residue system modulo $w_i$ in $[1, w_i]$. If $p_i \mid y_i$, since there are no elements to remove, set $R_{w_i} = R_{t}$ and skip to $5$.
4. Creating $R_{w_i}$ from $R_{t}$ requires removing all $mp_i, 1 \le m \le y_i$. Since all such $mp_i$ where $m$ is not relatively prime to $y_i$ are already not in $R_{t}$, the only ones remaining to take out are those where $m \in R_{y_i}$. This means the set of $mp_i$ integers to remove is composed of each congruence class of $h \in C_{x}$ of elements in $R_{y_i}$ being mapped to $hp_{i}$. The destination mapping is unique since if congruence classes $h_1, h_2 \in C_{x}$ have $h_1p_{i} \equiv h_2p_{i} \pmod{x}$, then $(h_i - h_2)p_i \equiv 0 \pmod{x}$, but $\gcd(p_i, x) = 1$ means $h_1 = h_2$. Thus, for each $h$, the number of elements of $hp_i$ to remove in $R_{t}$ are the same. Since the number of elements of each  congruence class $g \in C_{x}$ in $[1, w_i]$ were the same in $R_{t}$, they will now be fewer, but still equal to each other, after removing any multiples of $p_i$ from that set to get $R_{w_i}$.
5. Set $y_{i + 1} = w_{i}$. If $i = n$, then exit these steps. Otherwise, increment $i$ and go to $2$.

The final $y_{n + 1}$ is your $y*z$, with the reduced residue system modulo $y_{n+1}$ of $[1, y_{n+1}]$ being divided equally among each of the congruence classes modulo $x$.